# Android Tile Provider returns the map three times or more

Tags: android, provider, tile

[map screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOPE0.jpg) When I load a Google Map from assets png file as tile provider, it appears map three or more times
I have tried a lot and this problem is not solved
Please is there a solution to this problem ?

this my code

```
TileOverlay tileOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider).zIndex(3000));



TileProvider tileProvider = new TileProvider() {
        @Override
        public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(String.format("map.png", zoom, x, y));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int bytesRead;
                ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                byte file[] = output.toByteArray();
                Tile result = new Tile(256, 356, file);
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
```

Comment: `String.format("map.png", zoom, x, y)` Please tell which string you get for a zoom,x,y. And tell how often you call it with which zoom,x,y values? Add some log statements in your code so you know which zoom.x.y is asked.

Comment: thank you blackapps   .. i just call it like this : @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        TileOverlay tileOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider).zIndex(3000));
    }

Comment: You have not given the info i asked for. If you do not call it then tell how often its called. And tell the string values. Log them!

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably the wrong tile size in this line of code:

It should work fine if
`Tile result = new Tile(256, 356, file);`
is replaced by
`Tile result = new Tile(256, 256, file);`